# Does Azure SQL Database support In Memory Optimized Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, in-memory

I'm trying to look at the SQL Server 2014 and In Memory Optimized Tables and it integration with Power BI. And I'm thinking about what is the best way to migrate existing database (contains several In Memory Optimized tables) to Azure? Does Azure SQL Database support In Memory Optimized Tables?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for ServerFault, but... if you're referring to 'Hekaton' in-memory OLTP, that feature does not exist today in SQL Azure Database (vs installing in your own VMs, which you *can* do).

Comment: @David Makogon, thanks for answer, I'll be thinking what to do next.

Comment: I'm from SQL Azure team and I would be very interested to hear more details about your in-memory OLTP scenario. Sounds like you are using In-Memory OLTP a lot. Can you reach me to share more details, please? alainl (at) microsoft.com Thank you.
/Alain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx) it is supported in Azure Sql Database and not supported in Azure Sql Data Warehouse. As for Azure Sql Database, it is **in preview for Premium Azure SQL databases only**. It is not supported neither in Basic nor in Standard tier (see more details in [azure-specific documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-in-memory/)).

If you try to develop for Azure Sql Database using Visual Studio, both versions 2013 and 2015 will show you the following error message (your database project won't compile):

```
SQL71578: The element Table: [dbo].[*******] has property IsMemoryOptimized set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
```

At this point you have to consider SQL Server 2014 or 2016 in an Azure VM, but not Azure SQL.

Answer (score 7):

As of Q4 2020, Azure SQL supports In-Memory OLTP (aka `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED`) in only a couple of pricing-tiers. [This is half-documented in this (hard to find) Azure SQL documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-vcore?tabs=azure-portal), the other half I sourced from ancient blog posts and trial-and-error within the Azure Portal.

(Note again, this only applies to "Azure SQL" and not running the full-fat SQL Server in a VM or the Managed Instance service).

Here's a flowchart I made:

- Are you using DTUs or vCores?

  - DTUs:

    - Are you using the **Basic** tier (5 DTUs)? If so, then no, In-Memory is not supported.
    - Are you using the **Standard** tier (10-3000 DTUs)? If so, then no, In-Memory is not supported.
    - Are you using the **Premium** tier (125-4000 DTUs)? If so, then **yes, In-Memory is supported**.
  - vCores:

    - Are you using the **General Purpose** tier? If so, then no, In-Memory is not supported.
    - Are you using the **Hyperscale** tier? If so, then no, In-Memory is not supported.
    - Are you using the **Business Critical** tier?  If so, then **yes, In-Memory is supported**.

You can find out if `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED` features are enabled in your database by opening SSMS, connecting to your database (your *actual* database, not `master`) and running this:

```
SELECT DatabasePropertyEx( DB_NAME(), 'IsXTPSupported' ) AS IsXTPSupported;
```

If you get `0` then In-Memory OLTP is not supported in your database. If you get `1` then it is supported.

And if you try to do `CREATE TYPE dbo.Foo AS TABLE ( ... ) WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON );` you'll get this error:

> Msg 40536, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
> 'MEMORY_OPTIMIZED tables' is not supported in this service tier of the database. See Books Online for more details on feature support in different service tiers of Windows Azure SQL Database.

---

Wrly, I'm disappointed that for all the hype Microsoft has been building for In-Memory OLTP, it isn't available for the majority of Azure SQL customers. Even more surprising is that In-Memory is meant to reduce the IO burden, which should mean that In-Memory OLTP will reduce Microsoft's own operating-costs for Azure. I guess they're waiting to see how customers use it. Given the extra technical details and thorough-understanding of the system required to use it, it's possible that customers will end-up mis-using it - gotta protect users from themselves, y'know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does and I apologize that the docs are unclear on this.

**I am on the SQL team** & can confirm that as of February 2023 this is true:

> In-memory technologies are available in Azure SQL Database
> Premium (DTU) and Business Critical (vCores) tiers.

You can verify your database support with the following:

```
SELECT DatabasePropertyEx(DB_Name(), 'IsXTPSupported');
```

If that returns a `0` you will get `'MEMORY_OPTIMIZED tables' is not supported in this service tier of the database.` when trying to create a mem table.

---

**Aside**: You might reasonably ask, what about Hyperscale? Not yet.

---

References:

1. [Benefits of in-memory technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/in-memory-oltp-overview?view=azuresql#benefits-of-in-memory-technology)
2. [Error 40536](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/in-memory-sample?view=azuresql#error-40536)
3. [My sample script as a gist](https://gist.github.com/JerryNixon/9fdfee37af2a3519a52dc233dc8c4baf)